# Can you make it impossible to close a given window in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, plot, window

I run lenghty simulations and plot the results on a given plot window to compare them. If I accidentally close the plot window, these plots are lost and I have to repeat the simulations. Is there a way to make it impossible to close the given plot window (for example by disabling the 'X' icon)?

A straightforward alternative would of course be to save the results in variables and run a small plotting script to plot them, but I find this less convenient in this case.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to replace the actual close window request with something "inert". The following code should do what you want:

```
figure('CloseRequestFcn', @(h,e) fprintf(1, 'Not allowed, use "close %d force"\n.', h));
```

Please note that this will not make it *impossible*: it will prevent accidental window closing, but if your colleagues make practical jokes like messing with your work, then this need to be solved on human level, not programming level.

Comment: Thanks, just what I needed. And how can I revert this if I want to close the window?

Comment: @MWijnand You can close the window as adviced in the `printf` call, or use `set(h, 'CloseRequestFcn',@closereq)` where `h` is the handle of your window. But this will only set the handler, not close the window.